# Debug until variable reaches a certain value

Tags: java, debugging

I'm doing some java programming in Netbeans 7.3 and I have written a program that contains a complex while loop. It reads a file in, does some calculations, then prints an output file with some changes.

Something goes slightly wrong at the point where the while loop goes through the 158th line of the text (158th cycle of the while loop). Nothing appears to be wrong with the file itself at this point.

Am I being stupid when putting a breakpoint on the while loop and continuously clicking "Step Out" 158 times to see what's going on? Is there an easier way to do this with java? Like running the loop until a variable reaches a certain value?

Comment: Doesn't NetBeans have conditional breakpoints? Most IDEs do.

Comment: Why can't use use a counter and placed breakpoint in a if block where you check for count?

Comment: NetBeans has conditional breakpoints: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebuggingConditionalBreakpoints

Answer (score 2):

adding debugcode like

```
if (iterationCount == 158) {
   int dummy = 13; // <= put breakpoint here
}
```

is a practical alternative to "conditional breakpoints".